# Android app crashes when attempting to vote on posts

Tags: bug, android-app

Whenever I try to vote on a post with the Android app it stops responding.

This has happened to me on both The Great Outdoors, Ask Ubuntu, and Meta.

I'm running Android 4.4.4 on a 2013 Moto G. I am running version 1.0.66 of the app.

Comment: Aaand now it seems to be working. Not sure what happened there. Leaving this for now.

Comment: Just voted on this post, it works

Comment: Unstable release, dev already aware of that.